# How to do intersection in n number of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, javascript-objects

Suppose we have an array of objects

```
var users = [[
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 41, active: true },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true }
], [
  { user: 'barney1', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
], [   
  { user: 'barney1', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true} 
]];
```

I want to apply the intersection on the above objects. I have tried
 with lodash method intersection like

```
_.intersection(...users)
```

but it gives an empty array.

Comment: based on which property do you want to do the intersection?

Comment: do you want to get the unique items in your array ?

Comment: Suppose we have [1,2,4,5] [2,3,4,1], [5,4,3,1,7,8.9] if we intersect [1,4] should return, but this is an array, i need to implement same for array of objects

Comment: Yes, you can do this but not with _.intersection, you have to use _.intersectionBy, or plain Javascript. I updated my answer with your users as a 2D array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to intersect them based on whether all properties are same, then use [`intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#intersectionWith) and [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual)

```js
const users = [[{user:'barney',age:36,active:true},{user:'fred',age:41,active:true},{user:'travis',age:37,active:true}],[{user:'barney1',age:36,active:true},{user:'fred',age:40,active:false},{user:'travis',age:37,active:true}],[{user:'barney1',age:36,active:true},{user:'fred',age:40,active:false},{user:'travis',age:37,active:true}]]

const intersected = _.intersectionWith(...users, _.isEqual);

console.log(intersected)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, i have to intersect when each and every value matched in the object

Comment: @PremBhushanKarn updated

Comment: @adiga - you can pass isEqual directly (no need for the arrow function)

Comment: @OriDrori you're right. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `_.intersection()` since it will only compare object references in your arrays. You have to tell the intersection method how to compare your items.

For this, use the `_.intersectionBy()` or `_.intersectionWith()` method, give it the arrays to be intersected and as last argument the property to use to check for intersection.

Your users object should be an array of arrays (2D) according to its structure and how you use it:

```js
const users = [[
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 41, active: true },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true }
], [
  { user: 'barney1', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
], [   
  { user: 'barney1', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true} 
]];

const result = _.intersectionBy(...users, 'user');

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do it with plain JavaScript using `Array.reduce()`, `Array.filter()` and `Array.some()`:

```js
const users = [[
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 41, active: true },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true }
], [
  { user: 'barney1', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
], [   
  { user: 'barney1', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true} 
]];

const intersect = (arrays, comp) => {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.filter(i => arr.some(j => comp(i, j))));
};

console.log(intersect(users, (a, b) => a.user === b.user));
```

Comment: No can't use intersection by, is there any option?

Comment: @Prem Bhushan Karn, see my updated answer, you cannot use intersection, you have to tell lodash how to compare the objects in your arrays

Comment: @Prem Bhushan Karn, if _.intersectionBy is not an option, I added a plain JavaScript solution too